# tap back immediately after moving the map crashes application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, crash

I came across the scenario where in if after moving the map immediately if I tap on back icon while the map has not fully loaded
The application crashes.

What I can understand is Since the loading is still in progress and I tap back the the application releases the controller but the google map loads asynchronously in NSRUNloop (not sure). So that might be the problem not sure though.

So does anybody know what can be the issue and is there any way to solve this issue?
Please comment if more description required.

Comment: Post some code, follow a trace stack.

Comment: Putting the debugger don't make the app crash as if I debug the map gets fully loaded then there's no issue. Is there any way out to detect whether map is fully loaded or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is still searching for the answer

What exactly happening was that map view events were getting fired even if the controller was released causing a crash in the app.

So the solution is **Before** setting the value of *objMKMapView to nil* you need to set value of *objMKMapView.delegate to nil*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that when you close the view, the object that is the delegate for the completed map load has been deallocated, causing the crash with a bad access.

A good way to get to the bottom of these types of crashes is to use Instruments (part of the Xcode suite to tools) and go zombie hunting.

Comment: yeah I too think thats the issue.. but is there anything which let us know that map is not yet loaded So that I can disable the navigation bar and prevent user to go back until map is fully loaded